# Trying to join two tables on a zip - one table has no leading zeros, the other has leading zeros

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables whose key is a zip code. I'm trying to join them, but it's inaccurate because one table has leading zeros and the other does not, so it's not matching up.

Is there a simple way to format this? I have read access only, and no write access - so physically changing the tables is not an option unfortunately :(

Help! Thanks.

Table 1 looks like this

```
zip_code    msa 
00210      Boston
00211      Boston
00212      Boston
01431      Boston
```

Table 2 looks like this

```
zip_code   city
210        Boston
211        Boston
212          .
1431         .
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data please?

Comment: Just updated with sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "normalize" zipcodes by adding leading zeros using lpad function. It adds "padding" - in this case zeroes, so that every zipcode will have the same length. I assume that you have zipcodes of 4 or 5 characters, then this might work:

```
SELECT lpad(zipcode, 5, '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RIGHT` function [documentations here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

Which allows you to get x number of characters.

```
  SELECT RIGHT('00000' || zip_code ,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Vladimir Oselsky's and Voytevch's answers normalized the data to five characters. This approach should work, but I'm not sure how safe it is to assume that the first table's data will always be padded up to five characters, or that you can't have longer zip-codes. The other way round, normalizing both data sets to numbers, should be safer:

```
SELECT t1.*, t1.*
FROM   t1
JOIN   t2 ON t1.zip_code::int = t2.zip_code::int
```

Comment: Cast to int can fail if there are non numbers in zip codes oe empty strings. (`''::int` throws cast error)